# Triggers still working even put the wrong input

Tags: mysql, if-statement, error-handling, triggers, mysql-workbench

My problem is, even i put the wrong alphabet other than 'F' or 'M', the trigger still updated. Also, even i put the 'F' or 'M' alphabet in lowercase, the trigger still function. how i want to make the trigger not function if the input is not correct? such as putting the wrong alphabet with lowercase.

here is my code :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAllowance -- trigger name
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON tab_employee FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF new.EmpGender = 'F' THEN
            SET new.SpecialAllowance = (new.Salary*0.2); /* Count the amount of Salary times by specific amount */
        ELSEIF new.EmpGender = 'M' THEN
            SET new.SpecialAllowance = (new.Salary*0.05);
        END IF;
    END
```

Comment: Nothing prevents the trigger execution when provided new.EmpGender have a value other than 'F' or 'M'. If you want to generate an error then you must add ELSE section to the CASE statement and use SIGNAL statement in it. But the best way is to add CHECK constraint to this column which prevents incorrect value, or make this column ENUM('M','F').

Comment: thankyou so much!!! i use check constraint to solve my problem and it works!!!!!!! thankyouuuuuuuuu!!!! may god bless you :)

Comment: If the value in `SpecialAllowance` column can be statically defined from EmpGender and Salary then you may make this column not regular but generated one, and its value will be calculated automatically.

Comment: i use this, is this correct?


ALTER TABLE `emadb`.`tab_employee` 
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_gen CHECK (EmpGender in ('F','M'));

ALTER TABLE `emadb`.`tab_employee` 
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_uppergen CHECK (EmpGender = UPPER(EmpGender));

Comment: I do not see the reason to use 2 separate constraints. Specify case-sensitive collation for the column `EmpGender` - and you do not need in the latter constraint because for this collation `'M' <> 'm'`. Or you may specify COLLATE clause with case-sensitive collation for a column in 1st CHECK with the same result.

Comment: How can i make the 'f' or 'm' automatically UPPERCASE when user wrongly put it to lowercase?